# Linking issue with libcrypto: undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext'

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, cross-compiling, bitcoin

I'm trying to cross-compile [cachecoin](https://github.com/vertoe/cachecoin) binaries on a linux host using [gitian](https://gitian.org/) and i686-w64-mingw for a windows target.

The compilation works fine until the final step of static linking of the dependencies. This is what I get:

```
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
```

Google suggests it's a missing `-lcrypto` link or even `-lcrypt32`. But in the last line before it fails you can see it's linking both. What's the issue here?

My gitian descriptor is available [here](https://github.com/vertoe/cachecoin/blob/0.7/contrib/gitian-descriptors/windows/gitian-win-cachecoin.yml). And this is the [qmake project file](https://github.com/vertoe/cachecoin/blob/0.7/cachecoin-qt.pro). Full tail of the build log:

```
[...]
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -frandom-seed=cachecoin -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -msse2 -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstack-protector -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DQT_GUI -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_GENERIC_SHARED_MUTEX_ON_WIN -D__NO_SYSTEM_INCLUDES -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DUSE_QRCODE -DUSE_UPNP=1 -DSTATICLIB -DUSE_IPV6=1 -DCACHECOIN_NEED_QT_PLUGINS -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -DWIN32 -D_MT -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I'../../staging32/include/QtCore' -I'../../staging32/include/QtNetwork' -I'../../staging32/include/QtGui' -I'../../staging32/include' -I'../../staging32' -I'src' -I'src/json' -I'src/qt' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32/include/ActiveQt' -I'build' -I'build' -I'../../staging32/mkspecs/unsupported/win32-g++-cross' -o build/moc_qrcodedialog.o build/moc_qrcodedialog.cpp
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -frandom-seed=cachecoin -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -msse2 -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstack-protector -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DQT_GUI -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_GENERIC_SHARED_MUTEX_ON_WIN -D__NO_SYSTEM_INCLUDES -DSCRYPT_CHACHA -DSCRYPT_KECCAK512 -DUSE_QRCODE -DUSE_UPNP=1 -DSTATICLIB -DUSE_IPV6=1 -DCACHECOIN_NEED_QT_PLUGINS -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -DWIN32 -D_MT -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I'../../staging32/include/QtCore' -I'../../staging32/include/QtNetwork' -I'../../staging32/include/QtGui' -I'../../staging32/include' -I'../../staging32' -I'src' -I'src/json' -I'src/qt' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32' -I'../../staging32/include/ActiveQt' -I'build' -I'build' -I'../../staging32/mkspecs/unsupported/win32-g++-cross' -o build/qrc_cachecoin.o release/qrc_cachecoin.cpp
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--large-address-aware -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-s -lmingwthrd -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release/cachecoin-qt.exe object_script.cachecoin-qt.Release  -L'/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib' -lmingwthrd -lmingw32 -lqtmain build/cachecoin-qt_res.o -lqrencode -L/home/ubuntu/staging32 -lminiupnpc -liphlpapi -L/home/ubuntu/staging32 -L/home/ubuntu/staging32 -L/home/ubuntu/staging32 -L/home/ubuntu/staging32 -ldb_cxx -lshlwapi -lmswsock -lcrypt32 -lboost_system-mt-s -lboost_filesystem-mt-s -lboost_program_options-mt-s -lboost_thread_win32-mt-s -lboost_chrono-mt-s -L/home/ubuntu/staging32/plugins/codecs -lqcncodecs -lqjpcodecs -lqtwcodecs -lqkrcodecs -L/home/ubuntu/staging32/plugins/accessible -lqtaccessiblewidgets -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lmsimg32 -lQtCore -L/home/ubuntu/deps32/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0xbf8): undefined reference to `__imp__CertGetCertificateContextProperty@16'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x20f6): undefined reference to `__imp__CertOpenStore@20'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x212d): undefined reference to `__imp__CertEnumCertificatesInStore@8'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2208): undefined reference to `__imp__CertDuplicateCertificateContext@4'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2291): undefined reference to `__imp__CertCloseStore@8'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x23c6): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2648): undefined reference to `__imp__CertGetCertificateContextProperty@16'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x27cc): undefined reference to `__imp__CertGetCertificateContextProperty@16'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2bc9): undefined reference to `__imp__CertOpenStore@20'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2ce2): undefined reference to `__imp__CertOpenStore@20'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2d4d): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFindCertificateInStore@24'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2d7d): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2d94): undefined reference to `__imp__CertCloseStore@8'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2db3): undefined reference to `__imp__CertEnumCertificatesInStore@8'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x2e25): undefined reference to `__imp__CertEnumCertificatesInStore@8'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3777): undefined reference to `__imp__CertOpenStore@20'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x37a8): undefined reference to `__imp__CertCloseStore@8'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3829): undefined reference to `__imp__CertEnumCertificatesInStore@8'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x388d): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x38c9): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFindCertificateInStore@24'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x39ef): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
/home/ubuntu/staging32/lib/libcrypto.a(e_capi.o):e_capi.c:(.text+0x3a9b): undefined reference to `__imp__CertFreeCertificateContext@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [release/cachecoin-qt.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/build32/distsrc'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I'd rather post ask in the comments first, but I don't have enough reputation yet.)

Judging purely from your post (I haven't tried compiling the program myself), it could be one of these three issues:

- wrong order of libraries in the command line (try appending one more `-lcrypt32` to it)
- the import libraries provided by your mingw-w64 packages are incomplete (you can use `nm libcrypt32.a | grep ' T '` to check)
- the functions are imported incorrectly (`dllimport` vs. `dllexport` vs. undecorated, calling conventions, ...)

After examining the error log once more, I'm inclined to believe it's the first option, as libcrypto seems to be importing functions from libcrypt32, but `-lcrypto` is almost at the end of the command line and it's not followed by any `-lcrypt32`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very plausible.The first option is what I also suspect so far. Somehow the mechanics of the makefile keep swapping the order of the linkings and I got to figure that part out yet. Will try.

Answer (score 0):

According to lore CertFreeCertificateContext is contained in `crypt32` so you need `-lcrypt32`

OpenSSL typically gives you this but you need to call it right like --static

```
$ pkg-config --libs libcrypto
-L/.../lib -lcrypto
$ pkg-config --libs --static libcrypto
-L/.../lib -lcrypto -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32
```

The latter is right, so you need to get your program to use the libs right, in my case it's a configure setting

```
 --pkg-config-flags="--static"
```

I'm not sure why, it's like pkg-config doesn't "like" purely static libraries?  Huh?